# Bridging entity from subtype entity ERD design

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I have two ERD examples involving subtypes. I cannot seem to find any definitive information online or in textbooks on connecting other entities to subtypes and how far you can inherit keys from subtypes, if at all. Those with good eyes may notice that I recently asked a similar question regarding subtypes, but it was for a different scenario and so far I only received a referral to another question that only explains the basics of subtypes which I do not need - I feel this is a more advanced topic to solve.

My specific issue is I need to know whether the Bridging entity called ENROLMENT is allowed to inherit the PK/FK from STUDENT entity, a Subtype of PATRON. If so, is PatronNumber and/or StudentNumber attributes allowed.

The two ERD examples are slightly different. Version 1 uses PatronNumber from the Subtype Student. Version 2 includes another PK called StudentNumber. Is this ok to add as a PK and can ENROLMENT reference from this? Which is better, if any?

[image: ERD Version1]

[image: ERD Version2]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The first version is to be preferred, for the reason that with a single value, PatronNumber, you can obtain all the information about the student with a single join, while in the second case you need to perform two joins.

Imagine, for instance, that you need to know the name of all the students that are enrolled to the course number 3: you can simply perform a join between Enrollment and Patron, while in the second case you need a join between Enrollment and Student and then between Student and Patron.

If your application requires explicitly a StudentNumber different from PatronNumber, you can simply add the attribute to the Student, and declare it unique.